# Converted Currency Field

Tags: integration, automation, multi-currency

Our org has enabled the advanced currency management setting.

On the opportunity records, some of our deals from Europe is showing as EUR 10,000.00 (USD 11,764.71). It is a currency field that locks whenever an opportunity is closed won. However, whenever our business analyst pulls the data from salesforce to create sales orders, he gets the EUR amount. I want to make it so he gets the converted US dollars amount. I've tried to create formula fields to store separate number field that will convert the EUR amount to USD. However, this way, I am not able to use the advanced currency management setting that will lock the exchange rate whenever opp is closed won. Is there a way around this?

How can I make it so all the currency fields will have the converted amount available to pull from salesforce? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am gonna try to see if this works and will let you know! Thanks!

Comment: My implementation worked great. Thanks for all your help.